# Power BI API - How can I get reports from app.powerbi.com?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have some client that uses the [Power BI App](https://app.powerbi.com).
And with this API I want to get all the reports (`.pbix`) to my folder.

How can I get them?

Comment: Please describe your question more detail as much as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply open the report in your browser and save it as .pbix file:

[image]

If you want to do this using an API, you will need [Export Report In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exportreportingroup) REST API. To use it, you need to acquire an access token and add it to your request header. You can acquire it by calling some of the [AcuireToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) methods from [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).

You can use code like this (please note there is no error checking in the example):

```
string clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Obtain at https://dev.powerbi.com/apps
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";
string resourceUri = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
string authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri, new TokenCache()); // PM> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

var authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));
var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken);

string powerBIApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports/{reportKey}/Export"; // Replace groupId and reportKey with actual values

var request = WebRequest.Create(powerBIApiUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentLength = 0;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
{
    //Read httpResponse.GetResponseStream() to get the .pbix file
}
```

Comment: i want do to it using rest API - do you know what i need to enter in stand of "myorg" ?  https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups

Comment: `myorg` should stay `myorg`. You need to replace `{groupId}` and `{reportKey}` only. You can take these from the browser's address bar when the report is loaded.